# How to save Jupyter Notebook to HTML by code?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have a Jupyter Notebook program, which do analysis for me. After it's been run, I want to save it as HTML so I can view it later. (And then I can change the input data file to do analysis for other data.)

Typically, I do this by hand. This would look like

[image]

But this feels very tedious for me. So I'm wondering if there is any code can do this for me? Maybe something like

```
%save_html
# or with a file_name
%save_html file_name
```

---

Note: I have figured out a workaround for this. But I didn't find too much info by search, so I post it here and it may help someone else having the same problem. I'll post my solution as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you should be able to find a script in the same directory that has the `jupyter-notebook.exe` file.  Its name is `jupyter-nbconvert.exe`.  Run it like this:

```
./jupyter-nbconvert.exe --to html 'path/to/nb.ipynb'`
```

[Docs](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html)

Answer (score 22):

I'll give an answer myself.

```py
from IPython.display import Javascript
from nbconvert import HTMLExporter

def save_notebook():
    display(
        Javascript("IPython.notebook.save_notebook()"),
        include=['application/javascript']
    )

def output_HTML(read_file, output_file):
    import codecs
    import nbformat
    exporter = HTMLExporter()
    # read_file is '.ipynb', output_file is '.html'
    output_notebook = nbformat.read(read_file, as_version=4)
    output, resources = exporter.from_notebook_node(output_notebook)
    codecs.open(output_file, 'w', encoding='utf-8').write(output)
```

In the last cell of the notebook, something like

```py
import time

save_notebook()
time.sleep(3)
current_file = 'GMM.ipynb'
output_file = 'output_file.html'
output_HTML(current_file, output_file)
```

Comment: you forgot to import Javascript from Ipython.display before save_notebook()

Comment: `from IPython.display import Javascript`

Answer (score 3):

First open console and go to directory where your notebook is.
Second enter this command:

```
ipython nbconvert --to HTML your_notebook.ipynb
```

After that you will have new file with name "your_notebook.html". Thats all.

You can check [here](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/1/interactive/nbconvert.html)
for more information.

Answer (score 3):

just execute this snippet

```
!!jupyter nbconvert *.ipynb
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I use `!!jupyter nbconvert MY_FILENAME.ipynb` to only convert the one notebook. Note that it outputs `MY_FILENAME.html`. There doesn't appear to be a way to specify the output filename, so instead I use `os.rename('MY_FILENAME.html', 'new_path/new_name.html')` after generating the HTML file.

Comment: From where? Within the notebook, or from a console?

Comment: Use `!!jupyter nbconvert MY_FILENAME.ipynb --to html` in a code cell in the jupyter notebook. Be sure to save the notebook before running it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution purely based on code, executed within the notebook, you can use the following short code snippet, which will name your file 'test_1':

```
a = 1
command = f'jupyter nbconvert Untitled.ipynb --output test_{a}.html'
subprocess.call(command)
```