# ReferenceError: IPython is not defined

Tags: python

I am trying to save my jupyter notebook in visual code using the code from

[How to save Jupyter Notebook to HTML by code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37657547/how-to-save-jupyter-notebook-to-html-by-code)

But the outcome is

ReferenceError: IPython is not defined
at eval (eval at runCodeHere (vscode-webview-resource)

Does someone know how to fix it?

Comment: I am getting same error on using %matplotlib notebook